# Is there any anime continuing or inspired by Golden Boy (Kintaro)?

Tags: golden-boy

Has any anime been produced that continues the 6 episodes of [Golden Boy (Kintaro)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_Boy_%28manga%29) or is otherwise inspired by it?

Comment: It is very unfortunate that they did not make more episodes. The only anime I could think of that gives me a similar feeling is Great Teacher Onizuka. The character really shines through in this one just like in Golden Boy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **Golden Boy** OVA is only 6 episodes. There hasn't been any more adapted from the manga (which is a lot racier than the anime). The closest thing to a continuation is the recent "Golden Boy 2" manga which is outright pornography.

It's hard to say if there's anything that's *inspired* by Golden Boy. Tatsuya Egawa, Golden Boy's creator, produced lots of other manga and various degrees of pornographic films which you could say *might* be inspired by his other creations. Kousuke Fujishima, the creator of "Oh My Goddess", used to work for him as an assistant but I don't know of any interviews or sources indicating that he was inspired by Golden Boy.